# Cant open web broswer in my freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: 22.04, firefox, chromium, brave, webbrowser-app

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP4lu.jpg)I newly installed Ubuntu 22.04.02 version on my ssd using bootable usb. It got installed, when I tried to open any web broswer its not opening. When I tried opening through terminal upon reinstalling it I get the  error like the screenshot. I dont know whether there is a solution on this but please help me on this.

Comment: The Ubuntu installer does not create a password for the root user, so you running as root seems very suspicious. Also, the display manager doesn't like to run as root. So login as a normal user (not root) and try running Firefox again.

Comment: Thank you, its opening now after reinstalling as a normal user. I dont know why installing through snap store not working...